# Orchard CMS: Filtering indexed search

Tags: c#, orchardcms, lucene.net

I need to be able to do a search on a content type made up of some parts and fields.
I've added the data to the Lucene indexing using handlers/drivers for the parts/fields.
However some content will be flagged as private (Using a boolean field) and should only show up in the search if the user is an administrator.
I could create the filtered search with a query using the projection module, but would prefer using the index for this if possible.

Is there any way to either filter the results from the index, or maybe separate it into multiple indexes? (Without modifying Orchard)
Or any other options I've overlooked?